# Docker npx create-react-app .ができない

Tags: docker, reactjs

### 目的

Docker環境でfrontend直下に create-react-app .でアプリを作成したいです。

*ディレクトリ構成*

```
backend
frontend
 - Dockerfile
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM node:18.7.0-alpine3.16
WORKDIR /frontend
RUN npm i -g create-react-app
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```yml
frontend:
 build: ./frontend/
  volumes:
    - ./frontend:/frontend
  command: sh -c "npm start"
  ports:
     - "3000:3000"
```

*説明*
上記の状態で
`docker compose run -rm frontend npx create-react-app .`
とすると、 .には Dockerfileが存在するため 名前をつけてくださいというエラーが表示されます

`docker compose run -rm frontend npx create-react-app react-app`
とすると正常に作成できるのですが、それだと`frontend`ディレクトリの下に別なディレクトリが作成されます

`frontend`ディレクトリ配下に直接reactのソースとDockerfileを共存させたいのですが、どのような変更をすれば良いのかわからず困っています。

解決策をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dockerfile` を一時退避すれば良いのでは。

```
docker-compose run --rm frontend ash -c 'mv -fv Dockerfile /tmp/; npx create-react-app .; mv -fv /tmp/Dockerfile .'
```